$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\int_{X} |f|^{n+1}}{\int_{X} |f|^{n}} = \|f\|_{\infty}$ where $\mu(X) < \infty$ and $ 0<\|f\|_{\infty} <\infty$.
Question: Let $(X, \mu)$ be a nonempty measurable space with $\mu(X) < \infty$, $f\in L^{\infty}(X)$ and ${\|f\|}_\infty > 0$. Define $\alpha_{n} := \int_{X} |f(x)|^n $ for $ n = 1,2,3, \dots $.  Prove that
$$ \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_{n}} = \|f\|_{\infty} $$
My effort: First of all, it is clear that $\frac{\alpha_{n}}{\alpha_{n-1}} \leq \|f\|_{\infty}$, so that the limit is at most $\|f\|_{\infty}$.
For the other side, fix $ \|f\|_{\infty}> \epsilon > 0 $, and let $E := \{x: |f(x)| \geq \|f\|_{\infty} -\epsilon\}$ (notice that $\mu(E) > 0$ by definition). Let $g(x) = \frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon}$, so that $g\geq1$ on $E$ and $g <1$ on $E^{c}$. We can the write the quotient into (utilizing the fact that $\mu(X) <\infty$):
$$\frac{\int_X |f(x)|^{n+1} d\mu}{\int_X |f(x)|^{n} d\mu} = \frac{\int_X (\frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon})^{n+1} d\mu}{\int_X (\frac{|f(x)|}{\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon})^{n} d\mu}\cdot (\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon)
     = \frac{\int_{X}g(x)^{n+1} d\mu}{\int_{X}g(x)^{n} d\mu} \cdot  (\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon)$$
We then break the integral into $\int_{E}$ and $\int_{E^{c}}$, we have
$$\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_{n}} 
 =  \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\int_{E} g(x)^{n+1} d\mu + \int_{E^c} g(x)^{n+1}d\mu }{\int_{E} g(x)^{n} d\mu + \int_{E^c} g(x)^{n}d\mu} \cdot (\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon) \geq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\int_{E} g(x)^{n+1} d\mu  }{\int_{E} g(x)^{n} d\mu + \int_{E^c} g(x)^{n}d\mu} \cdot (\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon) $$
The rest are clear, We have $g(x) \chi_{E^{c}} < 1$ so that it is bounded by $\chi_{E^{c}}$ which is in $L^{1}$. We may apply DCT so that $\int_{E^{c}}  g(x)^{n}d\mu \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$. Then the result follows:
$$
\liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty} \frac{\alpha_{n+1}}{\alpha_{n}}  \geq \liminf_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\int_{E} g(x)^{n+1} d\mu  }{\int_{E} g(x)^{n} d\mu + \int_{E^c} g(x)^{n}d\mu} \cdot (\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon) 
    \geq \liminf_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \frac{\int_{E} g(x)^{n} d\mu}{\int_{E} g(x)^{n} d\mu + \int_{E^{c}} g(x)^{n} d\mu} \cdot(\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon) =\|f\|_{\infty} - \epsilon
$$
The result follows as $\epsilon$ is arbitrary.
Can anyone check if it is correct or is there a better approach? I think my answer is a little bit too complicated than it should be.

@operatorerror Yes! Thanks a lot.
